# Why this error is showing The argument type 'List<dynamic>' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'List<Widget>'

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

[This is the error causing in flutter code The argument type 'List' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'List'](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VZFbf.png)

[This is my list showing the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lYTTT.png)

Comment: Can you include code-snippet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because you just added `List scoreKeeper` which is equivalent to `List<dynamic> scoreKeeper`.

So instead, do `List<Widget> scoreKeeper = [...];`

Comment: Also, do add proper code samples in the question and don't mention 3rd party links showing it.

Comment: Thank you for your answer got it right !! Thank you for your feedback too

Answer (score 0):

Try providing data type on list like

```dart
List<Widget> scoreKeeper = [..
```

Comment: Glad to help, you can explore more about [type-inference](https://dart.dev/guides/language/type-system#type-inference)